# How to use a var that has been set in one html file in another html file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page that sets a value onclick using a js function. I need to use this value in another html page. I am unable to do it. It seems to reset the value when I use the value from the second page. The .js file has been included in both the html pages. How do I retain the set value across multiple html pages?

Comment: you can send it as part of the url, this is called the `GET` method, for example: `secondPage.html?myVar=cool`.

Answer (score 2):

Within JavaScript itself, you cannot keep track of variables across page loads. To pass the variable from one page to another, you will need to use a 'man in the middle' to help out. Either a cookie, or a query string.

A cookie would work great! I won't go into specifics of setting/getting cookies in JavaScript as there is excellent documentation here:
http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp

Using those set and get methods (which of course you could customise to suit your needs):

First page:

```
var yourVariableToSave = 'I like cheese and crackers';
var numDays = 10;    //How long the cookie should last.
setCookie('SomeCookieName', yourVariableToSave, numDays);
```

Second page:

```
var yourVariable = getCookie('SomeCookieName');
alert(yourVariable);    //Displays 'I like cheese and crackers'
```

If you only want the cookie to last the duration of the current settings, you can modfy the setCookie function to not specify an expiry date.

If this is for a single request, a query string might be useful. To do this, you could append `?someQueryStringName=YourVariableValue` to all links on the page, or inject the query string when the user is about to load another page. I won't go in depth with this option as I suspect a cookie may be a bit better.